# Hibernate Enverse in Java is using Proxies instead of Bags

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-rest, hibernate-envers, spring-hateoas

Currently i'm worrking on a Java project which uses JPA and under the hood Hibernate as its ORM.
Furthermore we're using Enverse as our auditing Library.

Now, when i query an entity which contains a @ManyToMany or @OneToMany relation directly through Hibernate, the embedded collections will get mapped to "Bag-Types" (PersistentBag for Lists and PersistentSet for Sets).
These Wrapper implement the "PersistentCollection" Interface, which handles the lazy Loading.
When the parentobject ist accessed, no database query will be executed (seen in the debugger). Only when i access an element of the collection, a database query is submittet.

But when i query the Revision through an AuditReader, the Collections will be wrapped in a ListProxy or a SetProxy, this leads to an "unexpected" behaviour (since enverse is a core element of hibernate). In this case, when i just access the parent object, every element in the embedded collection is directly queried. This leads to an enormous performance drop.
The Response from the Revision Endpoint is wrapped into RepresntationModel (from the Spring Hateos project). This leads to the access of the parent object and the generell collection, to create the "_embedded" Object of the response. With the PersistentBag there is no problem, but with the ListProxy, every Element gets queried from the database, leading to thousands of requests.

Is there a way to "teach" enverse to use PeristentBag (or PersistentSet) instead of the internal Proxy Collections or is there another workaround to not load the entire Collection?

Ignoring the embedded Ressources in the Revision boosts the performance, but is no solution since the references are Lost.

Enverse ignores the "fetch" configurations on Collection-Annotations (every Collection is fetched lazy), so this also does not do the trick.

Since the revision endpoint is highly generic, using projections is not an option.